# If statement inside Trigger not working SQL(Oracle)

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql, triggers

My goal is to create a trigger that checks if the number you are trying to enter *`NR_RECIBO`* is in the table `Doc_cabecalho` with the attribute `TIPO_DOC = 4`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ValidaRecibo
BEFORE INSERT ON Recibo
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE val NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO val 
    FROM Doc_cabecalho 
    WHERE (TIPO_DOC = 4 AND NR_DOCUMENTO = :NEW.NR_RECIBO);

    IF val = 0 
    THEN (-20502, ' Only from department 4 ');
    END IF;
END ValidaRecibo;
```

Yet, this raises the following error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:
>   * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem   <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec as between || member submultiset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF val = 0 THEN 
  raise_application_error(-20502, ' Only from department 6 ');

And you should decide between DOC_TIPO and TIPO_DOC ;)

Comment: Oh, thank you so much buddy!! I've been hours trying to solve this problem